# Chainlink - on-chain contract functioning

Tags: oracles, chainlink

The on-chain aggregation smart contract for ETH/USD on the mainnet (https://data.chain.link/eth-usd) is at this address https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#code.

If I create a smart contract and import the `AggregatorV3Interface` interface and instantiate `AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419)`, how can

```
function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
```

be enough to obtain answers from the off-chain oracles? I thought that, to communicate with an oracle for its jobs, one had to inherit from `ChainLinkClient.sol`. So, I thought that the smart contract for ETH/USD inherited from `ChainLinkClient.sol`.

I cannot understand the logic on how this aggregator contract can fetch data from the outside from the decentralised network of oracles as shown in the picture (https://data.chain.link/eth-usd).